# DateTime object not returning locale time

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to return to a user a days in specific language (cs_CZ)

I have this script:

```
  <?php
  $date = (new \DateTime($log['date']))->format('d.m.Y');
  $date_name = (new \DateTime($log['date']))->format('D');
  ?>
```

I made from that this, but its not working:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ');
 $date = (new \DateTime($log['date']))->format('d.m.Y');
  $date_name = (new \DateTime($log['date']))->format(strftime("%a"));
?>
```

What should be the problem?

Comment: I want to show date just in cs_CZ. How to replace that? Because date() always return a English date time.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way instead :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ');

$date = new DateTime($log['date']);
$date = strftime("%A", $date->getTimestamp());

var_dump($date);
```

Feel free to test this code [here](http://phptester.net/).